# simple Javascript data to jquery mobile selectbox

Tags: jquery

Please help me in this..
I have the data 
var data = '{"1":"xxx","2":"eee","3":"ddd","4":"rrr"}'

how can i set this to my select drop down box..

please help
thanks in advance

Comment: Show your efforts towards that.!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#dropdown").empty();
$.each(data, function(k, v) {
    var $opt = $("<option/>");
    $opt.attr("value", k);
    $opt.text(v);
    $opt.appendTo($("#dropdown"));
});
```

Comment: I debugged into the code and i got through to each and every line via alert..Thing is that in alert i am getting ",1,x,2,x etc as alert messages..please help me shall i change that string into JSON object??

Comment: after appending `$("#dropdown").selectmenu("refresh");` to enhance selectmenu widget. @user3185790